# "Incompatible pointer..." warning on assigning delegate to self

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, delegates

I have a custom subclass of UITableView with a protocol defined in it as below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(NSInteger)numberOfRows;
@end

@interface CustomTV : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{  
    id<CustomDelegate> *del;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)    id<CustomDelegate> *del;
@end
```

Now in some other class, I instantiate this CustomTV and set the delegate to self:

```
    CustomTV *tbl = [[CustomTV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tbl.del = self;
```

Why do I get an "Incompatible pointer..." warning on the line `tbl.del = self` ?

I did conform to the CustomDelegate protocol in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the delegate as a pointer to a pointer to an object. The type `id` is already declared as a pointer to an object so remove the star.

```
@interface CustomTV : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{  
    id<CustomDelegate> del;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)    id<CustomDelegate> del;
@end
```